# how to filter on a reversed relationship on Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this two models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    incorporated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employees")
```

If I do the following reversed lookup:

```
Company.objects.filter(employees__incorporated_at="2021-01-01T00:00:00+00:00")
```

Then I'll get a list of those companies with **at least** one employee that satisfies such a query. But what I want to get is a list of companies with **all** its employees satisfying that query. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the counts of the employees and the counts of employees where `incorporated_at` has the given value using the [`Count` aggregation function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#id8) and then filter on these two counts being the same:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Q


Company.objects.annotate(
    employee_count=Count('employees'),
    matching_employee_count=Count('employees', filter=Q(employees__incorporated_at="2021-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"))
).filter(employee_count=F('matching_employee_count'))
```